# Handling a Windows confirm pop-up using Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am learning Cypress the hard way: on a legacy app with frames :(

I read that Cypress auto accepts alerts but here I have a Confirm pop-up that demands a user input. However, I am struggling to close this windows confirm pop ip asking to 'Cancel' or 'OK'.

The element which fires the pop-up is within a frame (not an iFrame) is as follows:

```
<a href="/tasksgui/manageScheduledJobs.do?userAction=runnow&amp;userAction=select&amp;selectedIndex=1&amp;formContextKey=ListChunk[SchedulerJobsSearchResults]{1588676256461}1" 
onclick="return(confirmRunNow())" ;>
RunJobs</a>
```

I know that the Cypress API exposes a way to handle these:

```
cy.on('window:confirm', (str) => {
    //code here
}
```

But I'm unclear how to incorporate this into my test block"

```
it('gets the post', (done) => {
cy.visit('http://myapp.co.uk/mygui/index.jsp');
getLeftFrameBody().findByText('Manage Tasks').click();
cy.wait(2000)
getContentFrameBody().should('include.text', 'Scheduled Tasks')

getContentFrameBody().findByText('Task Name');
getContentFrameBody().find('input[name="jobName"]').type('Task one');
getContentFrameBody().findByText('Search').click();
cy.wait(2000)
cy.on('window:confirm', function(confirmText){
  return true
});

getContentFrameBody().find('.resultrowone').find('a').eq(5).click();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

By making the function async, you can await the window confirmation and then continue as seen in the example below.

```
it('gets the post', async (done) => {
  cy.visit('http://companyapp.co.uk/mygui/index.jsp');
  getLeftFrameBody().findByText('Manage Tasks').click();
  cy.wait(2000)
  getContentFrameBody().should('include.text', 'Scheduled Tasks')

  getContentFrameBody().findByText('Job Name');
  getContentFrameBody().find('input[name="jobName"]').type('runTasks');
  getContentFrameBody().findByText('Search').click();
  cy.wait(2000);

  await new Promise(resolve => {
    cy.on('window:confirm', (str) => {
      resolve();
    });

    getContentFrameBody().find('.resultrowone').find('a').eq(5).click();
  });

  // Continue after window was confirmed
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I tried this but the Confirm pop up still seems to simply hang awaiting user input